# pySpark convert a list or RDD element to value (int)

Tags: python, apache-spark, tokenize, rdd, pyspark

I'm using pySpark to count elements in a tokenized RDD.
This is one of the elements:

```
('b00004tkvy', ['noah', 'ark', 'activity', 'center', 'jewel', 'case', 'ages', '3', '8', 'victory', 'multimedia'])
```

I have to count the number of elements in the full RDD. It returns only one value, as a single element list.

There is a function to do that. I used this code (of course it can be changed, but it must remain on a single line, the Return one):

```
def countTokens(RDD):
    return RDD.map(lambda x :(1,len(x[1]))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).map(lambda x: int(x[1])).collect()

print countTokens(aRecToToken)

print countTokens(bRecToToken)

totalTokens = countTokens(aRecToToken) + countTokens(bRecToToken)
```

the result is:

```
[167]
[58]
There are [167, 58] tokens.
```

At this point I don't know how to use the result as a value (integer) and not as list.
My goal id to get

```
167
58    
There are 225 tokens.
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All those `lambda`s make your code unreadable. Your actual problem is easily solvable, but you would probably understand it if you were writing more obvious/maintainable code.

Comment: So in the very first map you loose your keys. Which makes me wonder why you are doing a reduceByKey instead of a reduce.

Comment: This is probably best answered on the edx board itself.....

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you both. Your hints helped me to solve the mess. @Justin, on edx board don't like code.

Answer (score 1):

```
def countTokens(RDD):
    return RDD.map(lambda x :(1,len(x[1])))
              .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
              .map(lambda x: int(x[1])).collect()[0]
```

the value is returning a list when you need the value in this 225. Adding [0] will give you this zeroth item in the list from which you can get your total.

But you really do not need the

```
x:(1,
```

if all your doing is totaling you just need len(x[1]) then to **reduce** like you have done.